# Rails pagy gem with turbo frame action results wrong url generation on pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo-frames, pagy

I am using pagy gem for pagination and turbo frames for interactive CRUD operations in my application.

I want to update **pagination** and **list item frames** with turbo_stream.erb actions when i delete some record. Everything works correct expect pagination links. They must be like...

```
/toponyms?page=1
/toponyms?page=2
```

But when i destroy a record pagination link occurs like below.

```
#because of deleted record id = 278
/toponyms278?page=1
/toponyms278?page=2
```

**controller**

```
def destroy
    authorize @toponym
    @toponym.destroy
    flash[:info] = "Toponym was successfully destroyed."
    
    # This code must be here for update pagination after delete 
    @pagy, @toponyms = pagy(Toponym.order(created_at: :desc))
    puts @pagy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
      format.html { redirect_to toponyms_url, notice: "Toponym was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


#destroy.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.update "total" do %>
    <%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>
    <%== pagy_info(@pagy) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have a similar issue with turbo streams.

Comment: This Youtube video helped me: How to Add Filtering & Pagination to Your Data Tables With Hotwire (https://youtu.be/HURqvNJF4T0)

Comment: I could not fixed updating pagination issue. Pagination works but updating after some crud operations is not work. Pagination links stay same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `:request_path` variable (available in pagy v6.0+) as indicated in [Customize the request_path](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/docs/how-to/#customize-the-request-path).

I guess something like the following should work in your case:

```
@pagy, @toponyms = pagy(Toponym.order(created_at: :desc), request_path: '/toponyms')
```